# Looker problem Pull Production Failed Pull Incomplete

Tags: git, pull, looker

I'm new in a company and I'm working with Looker. When they first created my personal branch in Looker, it gave me a problem: I didn't have any files; I reverted to production and all the files appeared, but when I tried to pull from primary branch it said "Pull Production Failed. Pull incomplete" and nothing more. We resolved that deleting my user and creating a new one with a new branch. It was working alright, at least for one pull and one push I made, but now I was trying to pull some committed changes my coworker has donde and now Looker has said again: "Pull Production Failed. Pull Incomplete". It's not like a merge conflict or something. It doesn't tell it at all.

I tried committing irrelevant changes like a commentary and also reverting my branch to production because I saw it works sometimes, but now I have old files and it doesn't let me pull because it gives me the same warning.

Comment: Could you elaborate with a [mre]?